# Mysql count record by day on a time interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of events (now around 2 or 3 million), with start and end dates (spread for several years).
I Want to know how many events exist every day. Not started by day, but happening each calendar day.
 E.g.

```
| name | start      | End        |
| Ev1  | 2019/01/01 | 2019/01/03 |
| Ev2  | 2019/01/02 | 2019/01/04 |
| Ev3  | 2019/02/22 | 2019/02/23 |
```

Expected result:

```
| day        | # |
| 2019/01/01 | 1 |
| 2019/01/02 | 2 |
| 2019/01/03 | 2 |
| 2019/01/04 | 1 |
| 2019/01/05 | 0 |
|     ...    | 0 |
| 2019/02/22 | 1 |
| 2019/02/23 | 1 |
```

Comment: Incidentally, when formulating examples with just a handful of dates, it's generally clearest to use dates after the 12th of the month. This seems inherently obvious, but needs to be pointed out remarkably often. Also, to add to what's been mentioned below - for the case where no event occurs on a given date, consider handling that issue in application code.

Comment: @Strawberry that is exactly why I use dates starting with the year. As I am almost sure there is only one format like that. I updated the question to show that I will face all types of situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, you need a date generator.

```
select
    d.dte, count(e.start) as cnt
from 
(
select dte from
    (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) dte from
    (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
    (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
    (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
    (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
    (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
Where dte between '2019-01-01' and '2020-12-31'
) d
inner join events e
     on e.start <= d.dte and d.dte <= e.end
group by d.dte
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be feasible to have calendar table for this kind of information. Then,

```
select c_date, count(*)
from calendar c
inner join events on e.start <= c_date and c_date <= e.end
group by c_Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky.  In MySQL, start with the dates and use a correlated subquery:

```
select d.dte, count(e.start) as cnt
from (select date('2019-01-01') as dte union all
      select date('2019-01-02') as dte union all
      select date('2019-01-03') as dte union all
      select date('2019-01-04') as dte
     ) d left join
     events e
     on e.start <= d.dte and d.dte <= e.end
group by d.dte
order by d.dte;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, but the dates are not that few as I now explained in my answer. But since I want to this analysis every month maybe I can script that some how.